# How to Query MongoDB With HashMaps value Using Morphia?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

This is a part of my code :

```
@Entity("messages")
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private long time;
    @Reference(lazy = true)
    private Payload payload;
    private String serviceName;
    private Map<String, String> headerMap;
    private MessageStatus messageStatus = MessageStatus.ESB;
    private MessageType messageType;
```

i need to find a document which

1. its headerMap contains "requestID".
2. the value of headerMap.get("requestID") equals "DUMDUMID".

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ds.find(Message.class).field("headerMap.requestID").equal("DUMDUMID").get();
```

Comment: Why is it so obvious now ;)